# Change "Shipping" text to "Delivery" everywhere I appears in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I only offer local delivery in my woocommerce store.

but there are several pages that refer my delivery method as shipping.

Ship to, shipping  type, shipping address,  free shipping, shipping date, shipping time.

is it possible to change or override every instance the word "Shipping" appears and change it to "Delivery" or "Deliver"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom **functions.php** file inside your theme folder. If a file named functions.php already exist, then you can use the following formulae. You can also create a functions.php file by yourself in the theme root folder if it does not exist.

```
<?php
/*
Functions.php file
Description: Site specific codes and functions
*/

function fix_woocommerce_strings( $translated, $text, $domain ) {

    // STRING 1
    $translated = str_ireplace( 'Shipping', 'Delivery', $translated );


    return $translated;
    }


    add_filter( 'gettext', 'fix_woocommerce_strings', 999, 3 );

//EOF
?>
```

Comment: You have no idea how thankful im to you for helping me out.

Thank You!!, Thank You!!, Thank You!!

Comment: @ODTV you are most welcome buddy.